# How to upload multiple files into C# and loop through them in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm having a problem with uploading multiple files to C# and loop through them. I found a question with a similar problem but nobody answered it.

I upload multiple files through an html input. The file count passes through to my controller with the correct amount relative to the amount of files I selected. However when I try to loop through each of my files it loops through the first file relative to the file count. For example if I upload 3 files it loops through the first file 3 times or if I upload 5 files it loops through the first file 5 times. It should not do this. I want it to loop through each file individually. Please help!!! here is my code:

Razor View(I'm using a bootstrap library for fileinputs called bootstrap-filestyle):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Initial", "DataCapture", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">

   <h4>Select files</h4>
   <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileToUpload" name="file">

</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Capture" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Initial(ClaimModel claimModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //OtherCode
        handleFile(Request.Files, c.ClaimID);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClaimFiles", new { id = c.ClaimID });
    }

 //OtherCode
}


private void handleFile(HttpFileCollectionBase Files, int ClaimID)
{

    foreach (string fileName in Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
        //OtherCode
    }
//OtherCode
}
```

I put break points on `handleFile(Request.Files, c.ClaimID);` and inside `foreach (string fileName in Files){...}`. As I said it correctly passes through the file count if I upload 3, 4, 5 or any amount of files however it only loops through the first file that amount of times and `return`s the first file multiple times as well. I need it to loop through and return each file individually. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Because you have one file input with `name="file"` so if you select multiple files, they all have `name="file"` and `HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];` returns only the first one with that name. Use a `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Request from server**, here is one example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
  var fileDoc = Request.Files[i];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try something like this:

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = null;

foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
}
```